# Streaming data into google bigquery template table with date partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to stream data into Big Query using templateSuffix and a date partition appended to the table name using Java API
But I am getting the below exception:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
"code" : 400,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"location" : "suffix",
"locationType" : "other",
"message" : "Table name should only contain _, a-z, A-Z, or 0-9.",
"reason" : "invalid"
} ],
"message" : "Table name should only contain _, a-z, A-Z, or 0-9."
}
```

I am using the API as :

```
String tableName = "testTable$201701"; // 201701 is partition_id
TableDataInsertAllRequest request = new TableDataInsertAllRequest()
                    .setIgnoreUnknownValues(true)
                    .setRows(rows);

// add a template suffix
request.setTemplateSuffix(templateSuffix);

return bigquery
 .tabledata()
 .insertAll(projectId, datasetId, tableName, request)
 .execute();
```

Only templateSuffix or only date partition on the table works fine. But not both together. Any ideas how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate use cases – streaming data to daily sharded tables and streaming data to daily partitioned tables

Daily [date-sharded tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) are those that have separate table for each day vs. [day partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) which is one table but partitioned “internally”

You can stream in any of those.
For streaming to happen – table must exist. So to avoid creating new table for each and every new day – [template table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables) is used (which is not needed if you have partitioned table).
So, either you stream to specific partition of day partitioned table or you stream to separate daily sharded tables using template table.
Not the both at the same time!

Comment: Well, in my case I have the date partitioned table. But it is exceeding the 100K inserts per second limit. (Mine is about 300K per second) So, what are my options? That's why I am trying to create multiple template tables. But I have to keep the date partition for obvious performance reasons.

Comment: just simplified option: you can just have let's say 10 tables each will represent modulo 10 on something that makes sense based on your data/environment. so you just have manage in your code which goes where. for example if you have multiple servers from which you stream to BigQuery  - you can modulo those servers, etc. Hope you got idea

Comment: Right. But I was hoping that using template tables would take the overhead off of managing schema of individual tables myself. In this case I have to create all those 10 tables with same schema myself. right?

Comment: you need to make it just once. rather than this  - from what I know these are two separate animals and cannot be used together :o( .

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, is there any advantage of using day partitioned tables than template tables (manually streamed to one table per day) while querying using table_name_2017_07_* and selecting event_time (timestamp) in between 2 days actually? like where DATE(event_time) > '2017-07-05' and DATE(event_time) < '2017-07-09' ???