# How to query multiple tables using wildcard for a particular partition in standard SQL of Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to query multiple tables in BigQuery using a wildcard (I have tables from _[0-9] suffix)

This query for a specific table works:

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM `maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_0`
where _PARTITIONTIME = timestamp('2017-01-24');
```

But this doesn't :

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM `maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_*`
where _PARTITIONTIME = timestamp('2017-01-24');
```

Error:
Query Failed
Error: Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONTIME at [5:7]

I am using standard SQL. Legacy SQL does not even take wildcard * in the query.

What is the way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like wildcard and partition do not work together in query

Try below. it is in BigQuery Legacy SQL as in this version it is less bushy
Assuming you have 4 tables, if more  - you need to enlist all of them here

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
  [maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_0],
  [maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_1], 
  [maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_2], 
  [maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_3]
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-01-24')
```

Of course similar can be written in BigQuery Standard SQL but it will require more typing with UNION ALL, etc.

For Standard SQL it can look like below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_0` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-01-24') UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_1` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-01-24') UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM `maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_2` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-01-24') UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM `maw_qa.rt_content_secondly_3` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-01-24')   
)
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks. A clarification - I hope this applies the partition filtering on each of the tables. Is that so?
Also, if the UNION thing needs to be done on Standard SQL, would it be similar and apply the partition on each table?

Comment: Hi Mikhail, could you also give an example how to do it with Standard SQL? I am trying the UNION ALL but do I have to have _PARTITIONTIME or any other column name on each select from individual tables?

Answer (score 0):

When you query a [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#the_partitiontime_pseudo_column), you don't need to use the `_*` syntax, which is reserved for table wildcards (where you filter on `_TABLE_SUFFIX`). In your case, you should just do:

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM `maw_qa.rt_content_secondly`
where _PARTITIONTIME = '2017-01-24';
```

Comment: Elliott, these tables are not template tables. So, querying without _* gives me error : Error: Not found: Table maw-bigquery:maw_qa.rt_content_secondly

Comment: Creating template tables with a partition would have been perfect. But seems like having partitions on template table is not supported - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817827/streaming-data-into-google-bigquery-template-table-with-date-partition